# Chrome falsely accusing me of cross origin request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, caching

I am having a problem with chrome telling me it can't load a local JSON because it is a cross origin request. Yesterday, this wasn't an issue for chrome. Now all 49 previous versions of this website, not just the current one I have changed a few things on, give this error. Previously, they were all loaded okay. The newest and all previous versions run fine on safari and firefox.

The only thing that changed was yesterday I made a new version of the webpage that ran off a server & loaded the data from that server location. Initially, I forgot to change the json load location to that server. Once I did, it worked fine. I've since changed the JSON location back to my computer and everything is running off my computer. All the previous versions of the website haven't been altered, but they are affected with same error.

*The only thing I can figure is chrome is somehow remembering that I once loaded from a server and falsely thinking either the index.html file or the json file is being run on the server or should be?* I deleted chrome's cache, but that didn't make a difference.

**Does anyone know what might happening for chrome to falsely accuse me of attempting to use a cross-origin resource?**

This is the error I am getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/justingosses/Desktop/Test2_localData/data/UpdatedBudget_201602_3noDash.json?_=1455733288536. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

This is my javascript code that loads the json:

```
function load__json() {
    $.ajax({
      // url: 'data/UpdatedBudget_201602_3noDash.json',
      url: 'data/UpdatedBudget_201602_3noDash.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      type: 'get',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("here is the raw json dataa"+data);
        data__json = data;
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("error");
      },
      async: false
    });
  };

load__json();
```

Comment: it looks like your running local host and are trying to access a file in the file system instead of how it would be on a production server

Answer (score 4):

The error looks pretty clear:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

You are trying to load JSON from your file system using the `file://` protocol, which Chrome is telling you is unsupported.

> The only thing I can figure is chrome is somehow remembering that I once loaded from a server

It was working before *because* you were loading from a server (which I assume was using the `http://` protocol that Chrome is telling you it supports).

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear on the particulars of the problem. The code I'm attempting to use now worked before. It is the identical code in the same file location opened in the same way on google chrome. file:/// protocol worked fine previously. Not only that, but the website on the server (using http:// protocol) gives me the same error. Yesterday, it didn't give me that error. That code hasn't been touched either. I'm assuming it has to be a change having to do with the browser as the code hasn't changed.

Comment: @JustinGosses sorry I'm not quite sure I understand. I am not sure why it wasn't working yesterday, but if you could provide some more code or insight, I can try and investigate a bit more.

Comment: I figured it out. It worked before, because a change had been made to the browser security parameters weeks ago to allow local access to files without being cross browser. I had forgotten about it! A recent restart of the computer apparently resulted in those changes being thrown out. Hence, things suddenly stopped working when security went back to defaults.

Comment: Option 1 @ https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally. is what was used to change the default browser parameters previously. Thanks for your help John & @Quentin

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, all requests for local files are considered cross-origin.

If you want to fetch data with XMLHttpRequest then use an HTTP server.